# Does WebApi EnableQueryAttribute end up with synchronuous OData query evaluation against SQL database?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

Let's assume I have two flavors of the same method in my ApiController:

```
[Route("GetUser1")]
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetUser1(Guid id)
{
    var user = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id);
    return Ok(user); // IQueryable<User>
}

[Route("GetUser2")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser2(Guid id)
{
    var user = await _dbContext.Users.Include("Customer").Where(u => u.Id == id).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(user); // List<User>
}
```

I make two calls and get the same results:

```
http://localhost:53916/api/User/GetUser1?id=7aa62ba7-98b1-4b7d-94a4-04fb0b41435f&$expand=Customer

http://localhost:53916/api/User/GetUser2?id=7aa62ba7-98b1-4b7d-94a4-04fb0b41435f
```

They are obviously materialized to the same SQL query, with WHERE clause and JOIN:

```
...
FROM [GetTruckMobileService].[Users] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [GetTruckMobileService].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Customer_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
```

The 1st method seems more flexible to me because different clients can choose which fields they want to expand. But I'm not sure about one thing: whether it holds a thread or not, while SQL is executed. The 2nd method uses `async` so it keeps the thread free. It's important not to hold threads busy with waiting while I/O operations are performed because then we would quickly run out of free threads in IIS thread pool. So, this is my question: **if I choose the 1st method, will it result in a blocked thread waiting for SQL execution**?

Please, note, that `[EnableQuery]` applied to the 2nd method would be LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entities, so `$expand` would not work there, if I wanted to expand some other field and pass this intent in the OData query.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the answer and looks like it is synchronous. Please check [the answer in github issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1203#issuecomment-357760692).

> ysmoradi commented on Jan 16 •
>
> Whenever you define odata actions or functions, you can return data
>   either sync or async, it depends on your code, similar to web api. But
>   in case you return IQueryable in your function/action which has
>   EnableQuery attribute applied, it applies $filter, $order by etc, then
>   it executes that IQueryable "**sync**" to produce response. This is
>   because every IQueryable provider such as ef, ef core, raven db, mongo
>   db IQueryable providers have their own async methods which odata is
>   not aware of. But every IQueryable can be executed "sync" using
>   foreach easily. Actually this is done at web api level, it's not a
>   odata thing. OData's EnableQuery applies odata query and leaves
>   IQueryable to web api. Note that when you pass $inlineCount, odata's
>   EnableQuery executes query to get total count in a "sync" way. It's
>   important to know that odata is a standard and it has nothing to say
>   about being sync or async. We're talking about asp.net web api odata
>   "defaults" here. You can configure that to make it async too.